# Ruby Mocha - how to specify ".with" multiple ".times"

Tags: ruby, ruby-mocha

I would like to be able to chain multiple `.with` expectations together. At present I am putting them on separate lines -

```
foo.expects( :bar ).with( a )
foo.expects( :bar ).with( b )
foo.expects( :bar ).with( c )
```

With `.returns` you can just do -

```
foo.expects( :bar ).returns( a, b, c )
```

I would ideally like to be able to -

```
foo.expects( :bar ).returns( a, b, c ).with( a, b, c )
```

or

```
foo.expects( :bar ).returns( a, b, c ).with( a ).with( b ).with( c )
```

Comment: Couldn't you open up the class and add a "with_all" method that would just do an each over the args?

Comment: Presumably so, but it seems like there should be a convention for this.

Answer (score 4):

You can't call `with` multiple times in the same expectation because `with` will override the previous one.

```
# File 'lib/mocha/expectation.rb', line 221

def with(*expected_parameters, &matching_block)
  @parameters_matcher = ParametersMatcher.new(expected_parameters, &matching_block)
  self
end
```

It's different with `returns` because `returns` accumulate the expectations.

```
# File 'lib/mocha/expectation.rb', line 373

def returns(*values)
  @return_values += ReturnValues.build(*values)
  self
end
```

So, yes, you have to do it in the way you're doing, calling `expects` multiple times in the same object.

```
foo.expects(:bar).with(a)
foo.expects(:bar).with(b)
foo.expects(:bar).with(c)
```